# Why is Solr not responding with full document on all nodes?

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

TLDR: go to the bottom

### Environment

I am working on Solr 4.10.1 (solr-impl
4.10.1 1627268 - mike - 2014-09-24 06:07:51) with a 3 server and 3 shard setup. As far as I understand there is a zookeeper involved.

The schema contains products and prices. The product data gets inserted/updated by one job and the price fields start out not being present in the document that is submitted. They get added by a separate job that only have the product-id and the price fields. For that, an `updateRequestProcessorChain` is set up:

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="versionable_chain" default="false">
    <processor class="solr.DocBasedVersionConstraintsProcessorFactory">
        <str name="versionField">price_last_generation_id</str>
        <bool name="ignoreOldUpdates">true</bool>
    </processor>
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

The cloud layout is as follows. I have simplified the names. The numbering is not relevant:

```
                  /-- box-3 (active)
       /- shard1--+-- box-1 (active leader)
       |          \-- box-2 (down)
       |
       |          /-- box-2 (down)
- foo -+- shard2--+-- box-3 (active)
       |          \-- box-1 (active leader)
       |
       |          /-- box-1 (active leader)
       \- shard3--+-- box-3 (active)
                  \-- box-2 (down)
```

I am currently not sure why `box-2` is showing down, but I am very sure that the issue was already visible when the box was still active and I am accessing the frontend there. A comment about how to fix that would be appreciated.

The data size currently looks like this. I have collected the information from the management web frontend on all three boxes.

On `box-2`:

```
foo_shard1_replica3:
  Last Modified:2 months ago (2014-11-30)
  Num Docs:234044
  Max Doc:262311
  Heap Memory Usage:1652112
  Deleted Docs:28267
  Version:5893
  Segment Count:10

foo_shard2_replica3:
  Last Modified:2 months ago (2014-11-30)
  Num Docs:303025
  Max Doc:324491
  Heap Memory Usage:1886264
  Deleted Docs:21466
  Version:7317
  Segment Count:11

foo_shard3_replica3:
  Last Modified:2 months ago (2014-11-30)
  Num Docs:349651
  Max Doc:397699
  Heap Memory Usage:1895080
  Deleted Docs:48048
  Version:8893
  Segment Count:12
```

On `box-1`:

```
foo_shard1_replica1:
  Last Modified:7 days ago
  Num Docs:299185
  Max Doc:348179
  Heap Memory Usage:1920704
  Deleted Docs:48994
  Version:23067
  Segment Count:11

foo_shard2_replica1:
  Last Modified:7 days ago
  Num Docs:379024
  Max Doc:443322
  Heap Memory Usage:2119024
  Deleted Docs:64298
  Version:26871
  Segment Count:12

foo_shard3_replica1:
  Last Modified:7 days ago
  Num Docs:373670
  Max Doc:414497
  Heap Memory Usage:2130464
  Deleted Docs:40827
  Version:29925
  Segment Count:12
```

On `box-3`:

```
foo_shard1_replica2:
  Last Modified:7 days ago
  Num Docs:299185
  Max Doc:314353
  Heap Memory Usage:1878904
  Deleted Docs:15168
  Version:22740
  Segment Count:11

foo_shard2_replica2:
  Last Modified:7 days ago      
  Num Docs:379024
  Max Doc:389958
  Heap Memory Usage:2044384
  Deleted Docs:10934
  Version:26338
  Segment Count:12

foo_shard3_replica2:
  Last Modified:7 days ago
  Num Docs:373670
  Max Doc:402724
  Heap Memory Usage:2127984
  Deleted Docs:29054
  Version:29598
  Segment Count:12
```

### Problem

When I am running a query for a specific document and return the document id and a price I sometimes get both fields, and sometimes only the id.

```
GET http://box-2:8080/solr/foo_shard1_replica3/select?q=id%3A%22product-id%22&fl=id%2Cprice&wt=json&indent=true&debug=track
```

The query results in two different response bodies. This one has the price:

```
{
  "response": {
    "numFound": 1,
    "start": 0,
    "maxScore": 13.212859,
    "docs": [
      {
        "id": "product-id",
        "price": 174.8
      }
    ]
  },
  "facet_counts": {
    "facet_queries": {},
    "facet_fields": {},
    "facet_dates": {},
    "facet_ranges": {},
    "facet_intervals": {}
  },
  "debug": {
    "track": {
      "rid": "box-2.internal-foo_shard1_replica3-1423579755522-18",
      "EXECUTE_QUERY": {
        "http://box-3.internal:8080/solr/foo_shard2_replica2/|http://box-1.internal:8080/solr/foo_shard2_replica1/": {
        "ElapsedTime": "4",
        "RequestPurpose": "GET_TOP_IDS,GET_FACETS",
        "NumFound": "0",
        "Response": "{response={numFound=0,start=0,maxScore=0.0,docs=[]},sort_values={},facet_counts={facet_queries={},facet_fields={},facet_dates={},facet_ranges={},facet_intervals={}},debug={}}"
      },
      "http://box-3.internal:8080/solr/foo_shard1_replica2/|http://box-1.internal:8080/solr/foo_shard1_replica1/": {
        "ElapsedTime": "4",
        "RequestPurpose": "GET_TOP_IDS,GET_FACETS",
        "NumFound": "1",
        "Response": "{response={numFound=1,start=0,maxScore=12.965124,docs=[SolrDocument{id=product-id, score=12.965124}]},sort_values={},facet_counts={facet_queries={},facet_fields={},facet_dates={},facet_ranges={},facet_intervals={}},debug={}}"
      },
      "http://box-1.internal:8080/solr/foo_shard3_replica1/|http://box-3.internal:8080/solr/foo_shard3_replica2/": {
        "ElapsedTime": "4",
        "RequestPurpose": "GET_TOP_IDS,GET_FACETS",
        "NumFound": "1",
        "Response": "{response={numFound=1,start=0,maxScore=13.212859,docs=[SolrDocument{id=product-id, score=13.212859}]},sort_values={},facet_counts={facet_queries={},facet_fields={},facet_dates={},facet_ranges={},facet_intervals={}},debug={}}"
      }
    },
    "GET_FIELDS": {
        "http://box-3.internal:8080/solr/foo_shard1_replica2/|http://box-1.internal:8080/solr/foo_shard1_replica1/": {
          "ElapsedTime": "2",
          "RequestPurpose": "GET_FIELDS,GET_DEBUG",
          "NumFound": "1",
          "Response": "{response={numFound=1,start=0,docs=[SolrDocument{id=product-id, price=174.8}]},debug={}}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This one does not:

```
{
  "response": {
    "numFound": 1,
    "start": 0,
    "maxScore": 13.2416725,
    "docs": [
      {
        "id": "product-id"
      }
    ]
  },
  "facet_counts": {
    "facet_queries": {},
    "facet_fields": {},
    "facet_dates": {},
    "facet_ranges": {},
    "facet_intervals": {}
  },
  "debug": {
    "track": {
      "rid": "box-2.internal-foo_shard1_replica3-1423579848055-20",
      "EXECUTE_QUERY": {
        "http://box-3.internal:8080/solr/foo_shard2_replica2/|http://box-1:8080/solr/foo_shard2_replica1/": {
          "ElapsedTime": "3",
          "RequestPurpose": "GET_TOP_IDS,GET_FACETS",
          "NumFound": "0",
          "Response": "{response={numFound=0,start=0,maxScore=0.0,docs=[]},sort_values={},facet_counts={facet_queries={},facet_fields={},facet_dates={},facet_ranges={},facet_intervals={}},debug={}}"
        },
        "http://box-1:8080/solr/foo_shard3_replica1/|http://box-3.internal:8080/solr/foo_shard3_replica2/": {
          "ElapsedTime": "2",
          "RequestPurpose": "GET_TOP_IDS,GET_FACETS",
          "NumFound": "1",
          "Response": "{response={numFound=1,start=0,maxScore=13.2416725,docs=[SolrDocument{id=product-id, score=13.2416725}]},sort_values={},facet_counts={facet_queries={},facet_fields={},facet_dates={},facet_ranges={},facet_intervals={}},debug={}}"
        },
        "http://box-3.internal:8080/solr/foo_shard1_replica2/|http://box-1:8080/solr/foo_shard1_replica1/": {
          "ElapsedTime": "4",
          "RequestPurpose": "GET_TOP_IDS,GET_FACETS",
          "NumFound": "1",
          "Response": "{response={numFound=1,start=0,maxScore=12.965124,docs=[SolrDocument{id=product-id, score=12.965124}]},sort_values={},facet_counts={facet_queries={},facet_fields={},facet_dates={},facet_ranges={},facet_intervals={}},debug={}}"
        }
      },
      "GET_FIELDS": {
        "http://box-1:8080/solr/foo_shard3_replica1/|http://box-3.internal:8080/solr/foo_shard3_replica2/": {
          "ElapsedTime": "2",
          "RequestPurpose": "GET_FIELDS,GET_DEBUG",
          "NumFound": "1",
          "Response": "{response={numFound=1,start=0,docs=[SolrDocument{id=product-id}]},debug={}}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### What I have done

While the data insertion jobs are running I have watched the access logs of all three machines. The inserts were more or less evenly distributed. All machines got some.

In the log that is accessible from the web frontend, I have found some errors, though those are a few days old and have not since occurred although there are regular update processes every few hours.

On frontend accessed through `box-1`:

```
1/31/2015, 8:14:51 AM
ERROR
StreamingSolrServers
error
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Internal Server Error



request: http://box-1.internal:8080/solr/foo_shard2_replica1/update?update.chain=versionable_chain&update.distrib=TOLEADER&distrib.from=http%3A%2F%2Fbox-1.internal%3A8080%2Fsolr%2Ffoo_shard1_replica1%2F&wt=javabin&version=2
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer$Runner.run(ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer.java:240)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

On frontend accessed through `box-2`:

```
1/31/2015, 8:15:13 AM
ERROR
StreamingSolrServers
error
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Internal Server Error



request: http://box-1.internal:8080/solr/foo_shard3_replica1/update?update.chain=versionable_chain&update.distrib=TOLEADER&distrib.from=http%3A%2F%2Fbox-2.internal%3A8080%2Fsolr%2Ffoo_shard1_replica3%2F&wt=javabin&version=2
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer$Runner.run(ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer.java:240)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

On frontend accessed through `box-3`:

1/31/2015, 8:13:02 AM

```
ERROR
SolrDispatchFilter
null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Internal Server Error
null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Internal Server Error



request: http://box-1.internal:8080/solr/foo_shard2_replica1/update?update.chain=versionable_chain&update.distrib=TOLEADER&distrib.from=http%3A%2F%2Fbox-3.internal%3A8080%2Fsolr%2Ffoo_shard1_replica2%2F&wt=javabin&version=2
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer$Runner.run(ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer.java:240)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

On `box-1` I have also got one about the Update Processor. I don't know if that is related.

```
1/31/2015, 8:15:05 AM
ERROR
SolrDispatchFilter
null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Doc exists in index,​ but has null versionField: price_last_generation_id
null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Doc exists in index, but has null versionField: price_last_generation_id
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DocBasedVersionConstraintsProcessorFactory$DocBasedVersionConstraintsProcessor.isVersionNewEnough(DocBasedVersionConstraintsProcessorFactory.java:328)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DocBasedVersionConstraintsProcessorFactory$DocBasedVersionConstraintsProcessor.processAdd(DocBasedVersionConstraintsProcessorFactory.java:399)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader$1.update(JavabinLoader.java:96)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec$1.readOuterMostDocIterator(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:166)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec$1.readIterator(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:136)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readVal(JavaBinCodec.java:225)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec$1.readNamedList(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:121)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readVal(JavaBinCodec.java:190)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.unmarshal(JavaBinCodec.java:116)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.unmarshal(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:173)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader.parseAndLoadDocs(JavabinLoader.java:106)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader.load(JavabinLoader.java:58)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:99)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:74)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1967)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:777)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:418)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

### Question

While writing this I have already seen that the replication has probably not worked correctly and that this could be the issue. However, this bug has first been reported 3 weeks prior to the date that the replication started to diverge.

So the question is: **Why are some documents not complete on all nodes?**

And the logical follow-up: **How do I fix that?**

I have inherited this system and I am glad about comments on what else I might do to isolate the cause.

Comment: Having a similar problem with a similar setup using solr 5.5.0
The only reference I have found on the Solr Jira issue tracker so far is this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-6771

Comment: @Steen I'm sorry to hear that. I never found a solution unfortunately, and I believe the project that this was used for has since been cancelled due to a management decision. We've had a local IT consultant with Solr experience look into it, but that guy couldn't figure it out either.